# changing array values depending on if statement

Tags: c, arduino

I need to constantly send 4 messages each containting 8 bytes of data to serial output in my loop function in arduino. The messages data which is send depends on the two digital inputs on my board. Here's how it looks:

```
uint8_t msg_1[8]
uint8_t msg_2[8]
uint8_t msg_3[8]
uint8_t msg_4[8]

uint8_t first_1[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t first_2[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t first_3[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t first_4[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};

uint8_t second_1[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t second_2[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t second_3[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t second_4[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};


void loop (void){

    if(input1 == HIGH && input2 == LOW){
        msg = first; // <====== how to assign it?
    }
    else if (input1 == LOW && input2 == HIGH)
        msg = second; // <===== how to assign it?
}

serial.write(msg_1,8)
serial.write(msg_2,8)
serial.write(msg_3,8)
serial.write(msg_4,8)
}
```

my question is how to assign one array to another in if statement? Should i use pointers or what?

Comment: and when you need a msg? You seem to be not use it at all.

Comment: Indent your code please.

Comment: It would seem that 2D arrays would have been more elegant here? Or just a single 1D array?

Answer (score 1):

Use pointers to the values:

```
uint8_t *msg_1;
uint8_t *msg_2;
uint8_t *msg_3;
uint8_t *msg_4;

uint8_t first_1[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t first_2[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t first_3[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t first_4[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};  

uint8_t second_1[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t second_2[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t second_3[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF};
uint8_t second_4[] = {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}; 


void loop (void){

  if(input1 == HIGH && input2 == LOW){
    msg_1 = first_1; 
    msg_2 = first_2; 
    msg_3 = first_3; 
    msg_4 = first_4; 
  }
  else if (input1 == LOW && input2 == HIGH) {
    msg_1 = second_1;
    msg_2 = second_2;
    msg_3 = second_3;
    msg_4 = second_4;
  }

  serial.write(msg_1,8)
  serial.write(msg_2,8)
  serial.write(msg_3,8)
  serial.write(msg_4,8)
}
```

Comment: note that you could use a struct with 4 members, so that there is only one assignment in each case, instead of 4

Comment: ah-ah....surely  at least my answer will have a `{` char to open the else if scope....;)

Comment: @LPs - it's a copy/paste of the original question, hence the formatting. Still don't see an answer from you... :-)

Comment: Posted, if you are curious.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a struct for the message and then define a matrix of that struct.

Example:

```
#define MESSAGE_SIZE 8

struct message
{
    uint8_t body[MESSAGE_SIZE];
};

struct message msg[4][2] = {
                            { {{0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}}, {{0x89, 0x81, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}} },
                            { {{0x89, 0x82, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}}, {{0x89, 0x83, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}} },
                            { {{0x89, 0x84, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}}, {{0x89, 0x85, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}} },
                            { {{0x89, 0x86, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}}, {{0x89, 0x87, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}} }
                           };

void loop (void)
{
    int index = 0;

    if(input1 == HIGH && input2 == LOW)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    else if (input1 == LOW && input2 == HIGH)
    {
        index = 1;
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i< 4; i++)
    {
       serial.write(msg[i][index].body,MESSAGE_SIZE);
    }
}
```

The best is to add requested signal status for each message:

```
#define MESSAGE_SIZE 8

struct message
{
    uint8_t input1;
    uint8_t input2;
    uint8_t body[MESSAGE_SIZE];
};

struct message msg[] = {
                            { HIGH, LOW , {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}},
                            { LOW , HIGH, {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}},
                            { HIGH, LOW , {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}},
                            { LOW , HIGH, {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}},
                            { HIGH, LOW , {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}},
                            { LOW , HIGH, {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}},
                            { HIGH, LOW , {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}},
                            { LOW , HIGH, {0x89, 0x80, 0xF8, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFF}}
                       };

#define MESSAGE_COUNT sizeof(msg)/sizeof(msg[0])

void loop (void)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<MESSAGE_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if ((input1 == msg[i].input1) &&
            (input1 == msg[i].input1))
        {
            serial.write(msg[i].body,MESSAGE_SIZE);
        }
    }
}
```